# Integral countour with Mangoldt function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In an analytic proof for prime number theorem I found a passage I could not understand:

> $$A=\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-\infty i}^{c+\infty i} \frac{\Lambda(n) (x/n)^s ds}{s (s+1)} = 
>  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-\infty i}^{c+\infty i} \frac{\Lambda(n) (x/n)^s ds}{s (s+1)}$$
>   where $c>1$, $x>1$ and
>   $$A= \psi_1(x)/x = \sum_{n\leq x} (1-n/x) \Lambda(n).$$

The book say that integral vanishes if $x < n$. Someone understand why?

Comment: See also proofs of the Fourier inversion theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the integral 
$$\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{x^s}{s(s+1)}\,ds$$
vanishes when $x<1$. To prove that, consider the contour:

[image: contour]

(image is from Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*, where you can also find the details of the proof). Elementary estimates shows that the integral over the arc tends to zero as $R\to\infty$, so Cauchy's theorem implies that the above integral is zero since the function has no poles inside the contour.